# Windows 8 - DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth Crashes - Error Code 0x800F0906

Tags: windows-8, windows-update, filesystem-corruption, dism

**Background Info**:

I have a virtual copy of Windows 8 Pro x64 running on Oracle Virtual Box.

When I try to install update KB2977766-X64, I receive error code **0x80073712**. This occurs when I use both Windows Update, and the standalone installer for the update.

The official Microsoft advice for this error - outlined [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957310) - advices that `sfc /scannow` be used first, and in the event that it doesn't work, `DISM` should be used instead. A number of other sources also state that using the Windows Update Troubleshooter in the Action Centre should fix this error.

- After I used the Windows Update Troubleshooter, the results stated that the error mentioned above had been fixed; however when I attempted to reinstall the update again, the error re-occurred.
- `sfc /scannow` does not find (or repair) any errors.
- `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` crashes with error code **0x800F0906**.

**Prior Experience**

I have had a similar experience with a Windows 8.1 machine before. The update in question was KB2977765-x64 (the Windows 8.1 equivalent of the update I am trying to install on my Windows 8 VM). Just as with my Windows 8 VM, it was crashing with error code **0x80073712**; however, in the case of my Windows 8.1 machine, I was able repair the error using the `DISM` command outlined above.

Based on this experience, I would imagine the same steps would work for the same issue in Windows 8; however I cannot do so as `DISM` is crashing in my Windows 8 VM.

**Question**

**How can I repair error 0x800F0906 when it occurs while DISM is running?**

I have ran `DISM` configured to carry out the repairs from both Windows Update (as outlined above), and the Windows 8 installation DVD (sources\sxs); however both crash with error code 0x800F0906.

My own research on this error has shown that it occurs quite a lot when installing the .NET Framework V3.5 on Windows 8 and 8.1; however .NET it is not installed on either my Windows 8 VM, or my Windows 8.1 machine.

Any help is much appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound - are you aware of any way that the component store can be repaired?

Comment: @Rahmound - it is a Windows 8 Pro VM that is **not** part of a domain. I attempted to run `DISM` previously using the `WinSxS` store, but this also crashed with the error code shown in the title.

Comment: I attempted to run `DISM` previously using the `WinSxS` store on my Windows 8 installation DVD, but this also crashed with the error code shown in the title.

Comment: I guess I missed that part of your question;  I am out of ideas;

Comment: No problem @Ramhound - thanks for taking time out to help me anyway.

Comment: 0x800F0906 = DISM fails to download the required files. Share the DISM and CBS folder from from C:\Windows\logs (copy both to desktop, zip them into 1 7z/RAR/zip file and upload the compressed data to a One click hoster) to see more details.

Comment: Hi @magicandre1981, thanks for taking the time out to contact me but I've actually managed to fix the problem. I booted up my Windows 8 installation DVD and choose the `repair` option. This basically restored a number of the system files to their original state. I had to reinstall almost 150 updates, and thankfully, no errors occurred on this occasion.

Comment: you should post this as answer and later mark it as answer.

Comment: I agree that you should answer your own question with the commented part of what you stated to resolve the issue so it's more obvious to people looking for an answer to this same problem.

Comment: @slickboy post the steps you did at this time as answer and accept the answer to "close" the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end up, I booted up my Windows 8 installation DVD and choose the repair option. This basically restored a number of the system files to their original state. I had to reinstall almost 150 updates, and thankfully, no errors occurred when trying to install the update after this.